# A vector bundle analogy of the Nash embedding theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E$ be a Riemannian vector bundle over a manifold. Can $E$ be considered as a subbundle of trivial bundle $M\times \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ such that the metric of each fiber is the restriction of Euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Should "trivial subbundle" be "subbundle of a trivial bundle"?

Comment: After applying Steven Landsburg's correction, this is a definition chase using the fact that there is a classifying map $f: M \to BO(k)$, where $BO(k)$ is the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $\Bbb R^\infty$, and the fact that $f$ factors through some finite-dimensional Grassmannian $\text{Gr}(n,k)$. It is not analagous to Nash's theorem (which is much more difficult).

Comment: Even more is true: if the vector bundle has a metric connection, then by a result of Narasimhan and Ramanan, there is a classifying map from $M$ to a sufficiently high-dimensional Grassmannian that classifies both metric and connection on $E$. This seems to me the correct "linearisation" of the Nash embedding  theorem.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg  sorry for my  delay. Thanks for your correction. I revise it.